# Navigate to a div in another component, with smooth transition

Tags: html, css, vue.js, inertiajs

I want to click on the navbar and then navigate to a div in the another page, with smooth transition.

LayoutComponent -> NavComponent -> NavLinkComonent

LayoutComponent -> HomeComponent (DIV)

[image]

LayoutComponent

```
<template>
    <Nav />
    <slot/>
</template>

<script>
    import Nav from "./Nav";

    export default { components: { Nav }, };
</script>
```

NavComponent

```
<template>

    <ul>
        <li><NavLink href="/#home">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink href="/#about">About</NavLink></li>
    </ul>

</template>

<script>
    import NavLink from "./NavLink";

    export default { components: { NavLink }, };
</script>
```

NavLink

```
<template>
    <Link>
        <slot />
    </Link>
</template>
```

HomeComponent

```
<template>
    <div id="home" style="height: 100px">Home</div>
    <div id="about" style="height: 100px">About</div>
</template>
```

Comment: maybe divs height is not enough for u to see it navigate

Comment: the project works, I want to add the smooth transistion.

Comment: add `scroll-behavior: smooth; ` to home & about divs

Comment: Thanks Rashid, I added : html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }, and it works.